# How would I use rasterization to create a texel to primitive texture-map - DirectX 11

Tags: textures, directx-11, compute-shader, uv-mapping, rasterizing

I have written a compute shader that is intended to use the UV coordinates of 3 vertices making up a primitive, as well as the texel coordinate (dispatchThreadID.xy) to achieve rasterization.

I am attempting to return a texture that for each texel, references the index of three vertices making up a primitive, in which the texel lies in.

It is my understanding that dividing the texel coordinates by the texture width/height (or vice versa) should put them in the same space.

Here is the shader:

```
StructuredBuffer<Input> inputBuffer : register(t0);
StructuredBuffer<int> indexBuffer : register(t1);
RWTexture2D<float4> outTex : register(u0);

[numthreads(16, 16, 1)]
void main( uint3 dispatchThreadId : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
// identify texel via various IDs
   float2 p = dispatchThreadId.xy;

   uint noStructs;
   uint stride;
   indexBuffer.GetDimensions(noStructs, stride);

   for (int i = 0; i < (noStructs / 3) - 3; i += 3)
   {
       int index1 = indexBuffer[i];
       int index2 = indexBuffer[i + 1];
       int index3 = indexBuffer[i + 2];

       float2 v0 = float2(inputBuffer[index1].Tex.x, inputBuffer[index1].Tex.y);
       float2 v1 = float2(inputBuffer[index2].Tex.x, inputBuffer[index2].Tex.y);
       float2 v2 = float2(inputBuffer[index3].Tex.x, inputBuffer[index3].Tex.y);


       float inverse = 1 / 512.0f;
       float2 p2 = p;
       p.x *= inverse;
       p.y *= inverse;

       // Determine barycentric coordinates
       float w0 = orient2d(v1, v2, p);
       float w1 = orient2d(v2, v0, p);
       float w2 = orient2d(v0, v1, p);

       // If p is on or inside all edges
       if (w0 >= -0.01f && w1 >= -0.01f && w2 >= -0.01f)
       {
           // save reference to that primitive
           outTex[p2] = float4(i, i+1, i+2, 1);
       }
   }  
}
```

Here is the Orient2D function that calculates the barycentric coordinates:

```
float orient2d(const float2 a, const float2 b, const float2 c)
{
   return (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y) * (c.x - a.x);
}
```

And here is a sample of the results from the shader:

```
Texel Map ( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 213, 214, 215, 1)( 213, 214, 215, 1)( 213, 214, 215, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 351, 352, 353, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 387, 388, 389, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 363, 364, 365, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 585, 586, 587, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 348, 349, 350, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 333, 334, 335, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 249, 250, 251, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 252, 253, 254, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 273, 274, 275, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 159, 160, 161, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 177, 178, 179, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 171, 172, 173, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 384, 385, 386, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 156, 157, 158, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 141, 142, 143, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 129, 130, 131, 1)( 213, 214, 215, 1)( 213, 214, 215, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)( 321, 322, 323, 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have relaxed the edge criteria discerning if the texel lies within all three edges to -0.01 instead of 0. This results in each texel being mapped to a primitive, but I don't think all primitives get mapped to a texel, which I think would be wrong. I think that is due to the loop continuing after mapping a texel, but if I include a break function within the if statement, the higher primitive indices are never reached.

Comment: You have to apply "conservative rasterization" rules, instead of testing p, you need to test for the full texel rectangle to prevent misses. Don't forget a texture texel center is located at (u+0.5) also. You are not giving enough details of your use case, but it is very likely for a texel to be covered by multiple triangles. You need more than just one output, you need a count texture and a texture array for triangle id ( no need to store the 3 index, that are indexN and not iN btw ).

Comment: @galop1n You are right about "index" instead of "i", that was silly. The intention is to map each texel to a primitive, then using barycentric coordinates to interpolate the vertices (of that primitive) data for said texel. I'm then using that interpolated data to render from in another compute shader. Effectively a texture-space render pipeline.

Comment: [Rendered output](https://i.imgur.com/7nnf3to.png)

this shows how it is rendering currently. sphere on the left is how it should look. It appears that it is calculating roughly the correct colours, just not in the right place.